# Разбор слова устарелость по составу

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, где ошибка в данном разборе и почему.

устарелость у - приставка, стар-корень, суффиксы: ел и ость, нулевое окончание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> где ошибка в данном разборе и почему

Ошибка здесь:

> суффиксы: ел и ость

Правильно: суффиксы ***е***, ***л*** и ***ость***.

См. словообразовательную цепочку:

**стар**(ый) -> стар-**е**-ть -> **у**-стареть -> устаре-**л**(ый) -> устарел-**ость**